# Sorting an array using Quick Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I recently learnt quick Sort algorithm and tried implementing the same taking first element as pivot. Here is my code :

```
    class QuickSort {
    static int partition(int a[], int lb, int ub) {

        int start = lb;
        int end = ub;
        int pivot = a[lb];
        while (start < end) {
            while (pivot>=a[start])
                start++;
            while (a[end] > pivot)
                end--;
            if (start < end) {
                int temp = a[start];
                a[start] = a[end];
                a[end] = temp;
            }
        }
        int temp = a[end];
        a[end] = a[lb];
        a[lb] = temp;
        return end;
    }

    static void quickSort(int a[], int lb, int ub) {
        if (lb < ub) {
            int pivot = partition(a, lb, ub);
            quickSort(a, lb, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(a, pivot + 1, ub);
            
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 1,2,3,5,4 };
        quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
            }
    }
}
```

I checked quick sort programs online and could not figure out any dissimilarities between those and my program. This program is working fine for the first three iterations but is giving error when the pivot becomes 5.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:11)
    at QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:29)
    at QuickSort.main(QuickSort.java:45)
```

But this code is working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    int pivot = arr[low];
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (pivot >= arr[i])
            i++;
        while (pivot < arr[j])
            j--;
        if (i < j)
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    swap(arr[low], arr[j]);
    return j;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,4};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    cout<<"Before Sorting"<<endl;
    printArray(arr, size);
    quickSort(arr, 0, size - 1);
    cout<<"After Sorting"<<endl;
    printArray(arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find what I am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: not familiar we the algo so might be missing the point - but: technically the inner while loops need guards against off range indices, something like `while(start < a.length && pivot >= a[start]` because you are inc/dec the indices

Answer (score 0):

your array has elements so the last index will be 4 (0-4).
When your pivot value =5 -> next element is 4 the start index will be increase 2 times -> current start index become 5-> out of range

Comment: Yes I understood that by debugging my code but how is the 2nd code working fine when i=5 and returning the sorted array?

Comment: I tried your second code but it returns outbound exception too.